# How to fix ReportViewer 11 render SSRS report too longer on IE, but not on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, reportviewer

IE display report too long. Chrome display report correctly.

Picture 1 (below) is on IE, which is using the reportviewer 11 rendering the SSRS report. The report goes out the height of page. Picture 2 (below) is showing in the chrome, which is what I need.

The following is the front code I used.

```html
<div id="reportRender" style="Width:1080px; Height:1000px;">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"  Width="1080px" Height="1000px" AsyncRendering="False"  Visible="false">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Internet Explorer

[image]

Google Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fix the issue by myself. The magic is to add overflow:auto on the style of reportRender. Then, the report exceeds the limit of the page issue is fixed.

Here is my code. Hope it will help someone else.

```html
                <div id="reportRender" style="Width:1080px; Height:1000px; overflow:auto">
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"  Width="1080px" Height="1000px" AsyncRendering="False" SizeToReportContent="true" Visible="false">
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                </div>
```

Comment: SizeToReportContent="true" could fix the two scrollbars issue.